# How to explode two columns of lists with different length using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns of lists:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['x1','x2','x3', 'x4'], 'B':[['v1','v2'],['v3','v4'],['v6'],['v7','v8']], 'C':[['c1','c2'],['c3','c4'],['c5','c6'],['c7']]})
>>> df
    A         B         C
0  x1  [v1, v2]  [c1, c2]
1  x2  [v3, v4]  [c3, c4]
2  x3      [v6]  [c5, c6]
3  x4  [v7, v8]      [c7]
```

I would like to explode columns B and C, so the output looks like this:

```py
>>> df_exploded
    A         B         C
0  x1        v1        c1
1  x1        v2        c2
2  x2        v3        c3
3  x2        v4        c4
4  x3        v6        c5
5  x3        v6        c6
6  x4        v7        c7
7  x4        v8        c7
```

My current solution is to first separate rows where elements in column B and C have the same length and run `df.explode(["B", "C"])` and for the rest rows, run `df.explode("B")` followed by `df.explode("C")`

I am wondering if there's a better solution.

Comment: You want two subtly different things here, for lists of equal length, you zip the lists into pairs (e.g. (v1, c1) and (v2, c2)). But for lists of unequal length, you want the combinations (e.g. (v6, c5) and (v6, c6)). Since you want two _separate_ outcomes, you'll be stuck with your current solution where you separate the two different cases.

Comment: This question is currently lacking detail / is opinion-based. What do you mean by 'better', in objective terms? Are you experiencing an actual problem that you need solved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `itertools.zip_longest`

```
import itertools

df1 = (df.apply(lambda x: list(itertools.zip_longest(x['B'], x['C'])), axis=1)
       .explode()
       .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x, index=['B', 'C']))
       .groupby(level=0).ffill())
```

`df1`

```
    B   C
0   v1  c1
0   v2  c2
1   v3  c3
1   v4  c4
2   v6  c5
2   v6  c6
3   v7  c7
3   v8  c7
```

get desired output by using `df1`

```
df[['A']].join(df1)
```

output:

```
    A   B   C
0   x1  v1  c1
0   x1  v2  c2
1   x2  v3  c3
1   x2  v4  c4
2   x3  v6  c5
2   x3  v6  c6
3   x4  v7  c7
3   x4  v8  c7
```

if you want, you can use `reset_index` for index

Answer (score -3):

Yes, there is a better solution. Instead of separating the rows where the lists in columns B and C have the same length, you can use the `explode` method on both columns at the same time, and it will automatically take care of rows where the lists have different lengths. Here's how you can do it:

```
df_exploded = df.explode(["B", "C"])
```

This will give you the expected output:

```
    A         B         C
0  x1        v1        c1
1  x1        v2        c2
2  x2        v3        c3
3  x2        v4        c4
4  x3        v6        c5
5  x3        v6        c6
6  x4        v7        c7
7  x4        v8        c7
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When I tried this I got the error: `ValueError: columns must have matching element counts`. Maybe I need to update my pandas?

Comment: I tested with pandas 1.4.2 and 1.5.2 and got the same error.

Comment: This answer results in error as mentioned by OP.